# hx711 and load cell read out 0 for calibration

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, sensors, pins, code-review

I'm using this tutorial from Sparkfun
https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/load-cell-amplifier-hx711-breakout-hookup-guide

And using THEIR code. The only difference is I added a delay so it wouldn't write a reading 10x a second.

**QUESTION:**
**How do I get nonzeros?**

```
#include "HX711.h"
#define DOUT  3
#define CLK  2
HX711 scale(DOUT, CLK);
float calibration_factor = -7050; //-7050 worked for my 440lb max scale setup
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("HX711 calibration sketch");
  Serial.println("Remove all weight from scale");
  Serial.println("After readings begin, place known weight on scale");
  Serial.println("Press + or a to increase calibration factor");
  Serial.println("Press - or z to decrease calibration factor");
  scale.set_scale();
  scale.tare(); //Reset the scale to 0
  long zero_factor = scale.read_average(); //Get a baseline reading
  Serial.print("Zero factor: "); //This can be used to remove the need to tare the scale. Useful in permanent scale projects.
  Serial.println(zero_factor);
}
void loop() {
  scale.set_scale(calibration_factor); //Adjust to this calibration factor
  Serial.print("Reading: ");
  Serial.print(scale.get_units(), 20);
  Serial.print(" lbs"); //Change this to kg and re-adjust the calibration factor if you follow SI units like a sane person
  Serial.print(" calibration_factor: ");
  Serial.print(calibration_factor);
  Serial.println();
  if(Serial.available())
  {
    char temp = Serial.read();
    if(temp == '+' || temp == 'a')
      calibration_factor += 10;
    else if(temp == '-' || temp == 'z')
      calibration_factor -= 10;
  }
  delay(2000);
}
```

NOTE: I did not yet solder anything because I don't want to mess up the soldering and have to buy new cells and wait a week for shipping. So I placed pinheads in the amplifier and connected with m/f jumpers, and used alligator clips to connect to the loose wires.

[image: load cell between 2 boards, as instructed]
[image: hookup 1]
[image: hookup 2]
[image: readout]

Comment: what does this mean? ... `How do I get nonzeros?`

Comment: picture #1 shows the type of loadcell .... why did you include the other two pictures? ... they show nothing useful

Comment: @jsotola thank you so much for your insight, but just because YOU don't know something, it's not nice to say my images are useless. What they show is that I did not have the VDD connected to 5v, and that was actually the problem. And a "nonzero" is something other than 0.

Comment: `they show is that I did not have the VDD connected to 5v` ... actually, they do not show that .... the pictures are not a clear view of the wire routing

Comment: i thought about your comment .... `it's not nice to say my images are useless`  and `but just because YOU don't know something`  .... you are correct, i have no idea how everything is connected ... you are the only one that knows how it is connected .... your pictures do not show the connections in a clear way, therefore they are useless .... it has nothing to do with being nice or not nice, but it has to do with the quality of the information that you presented

Comment: @jsotola, well the SparkFun folks were able to tell from the exact same pictures, so clearly you are not qualified to make such an assessment.

Answer (score 0):

Only VCC was connected to 5v. Had to add a breadboard to connect VDD as well.

(The kind folks at Sparkfun were able to help me out)